# Removing the Tab after the second pipe operator when using R in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio

The Ctrl+ Shift+m shortcut which is used to create the pipe operator in RStudio automatically jumps to a new line and creates a tab. I replciated this in Visual Studio Code in the keybindings.json settings. Although this works well for the first new line that the shortcut creates, it messes up the structure of the code in the second and subsequent line as new tabs are generated after every pipe. How can I edit the settings code to create the pipe operator, jump to a new line and create a new tab at the first call but only create the pipe operator and jump to a new line in the second and subsequent initiations of the pipe operator without creating new tabs?

This is the code I used to create the pipe operator shortcut:

```
// Pipe operator
    {
        "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
        "command": "type",
        "args": { "text": " %>%\n\     " },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
    }
```

The code above results in the following:

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(gear_ratio = gear / carb) %>%
        select(mpg, gear_ratio) %>%
            arrange(desc(gear_ratio)) %>%
                head(3)
```

However, I would like the resultant code to appear like the follwoing:

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(gear_ratio = gear / carb) %>%
    select(mpg, gear_ratio) %>%
    arrange(desc(gear_ratio)) %>%
    head(3)
```

Comment: I think when you insert a pipe operator in R studio, doesnt automatically inserts a newline but indents the subsequent line when you press enter.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved for the most part by Renkun using languageserver as appears in this post:

https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/321

Install the vscode extension R Editor Support and paste this into the JSON settings of vscode:

```
editor.formatOnType = true
```

Hope it helps